# clear selectedBackground to a highlighted uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to have an UIimageview's image change to it's highlighted image when the cell it is in is selected. The problem is that I do not want the cell's background color to change when it is selected. I tried overriding the coloring by using.

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

However, this had no effect. I do not want to set the cell's selectiontype to None because then the cell cannot be selected/highlighted so the cell's imageview is never switched to highlighted state.

Please let me know how I can control the background color of a selected cell and override the color change.

Comment: You can create subclass of UITableViewCell and override - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated method, and do in it every you whant

Answer (score 0):

You can create subclass of UITableViewCell, and override  `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated` method, it gives you really flexible ability to custom your selection

also you can see
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

[Custom UITableViewCell and animation on setSelected:animated:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982942/custom-uitableviewcell-and-animation-on-setselectedanimated)

[Changing elements in selected UITableViewCell subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436058/changing-elements-in-selected-uitableviewcell-subclass)

[UITableViewCell subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234947/uitableviewcell-subclass)

Answer (score 0):

With UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone, you can still use -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath.  It will be called even though there's no visible indication on screen.

Comment: I think that encapsulate UITableViewCell related logic in UITableViewCell subclass will be better. Am I wrong? It seems like every cell has its own UIImageView

Comment: but at the end of the call all highlighted statuses for things inside the cell are set to NO

Comment: @PavelKatunin you're not wrong. But in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, you can get the cell by using cellForRowAtIndexPath and then call methods on that if you want.